# Laravel 5 - Can I use a Facade within a service provider without registering it?

Tags: php, laravel, package

I'm currently developing a set of packages/service providers to use as a sort of boilerplate for new web applications. I started developing some time ago and I never ran the packages through composer.

After I made a repository and added the package to a new Laravel application, it installed just fine, until it ran `php artisan package:discover`. The error was:

```
In breadcrumbs.php line 5:

Class 'Athena' not found
```

and it refers to this line:

```
Breadcrumbs::register( \Athena::getFacadeRoot()->route_name_prefix . '.dashboard.show', function ( $breadcrumbs ) {
```

in which `\Athena::` is a facade within the package. I fixed the issue by adding the facade to the `app.php` file. The idea was to bootstrap applications easily, so my question is:

Can I use a facade within a package and still use the Laravel package discovery, without having to edit files when I create a new project?

Comment: have you tried with the full path?

Comment: What `\Athena::getFacadeRoot()->route_name_prefix` this will return ?

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth Thanks, it works with the full path. Stupid I didn't think of that... I'm still looking for a way to use the alias, though, because otherwise, the code will look a lot uglier and I have to change a LOT of files.

Comment: @KPK It returns something from a config file. The `route_name_prefix` is a variable in the `Athena` class. In this case, it will return 'athena.'

Comment: @RobanReuvers take a look https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19420

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth Thanks, although the described functionality only registeres service providers, not facades, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @KPK facades also support http://laravel-news.com/package-auto-discovery

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth Oh wow, thanks!

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth yeah cool, This is what I try to say. But I douted in the path.

Comment: @KPK lol i tagged you instead of op :D

Comment: @SupunFictionPraneeth i think you can answer to this

Comment: @KPK i think it doesn't have an exactly one answer